# Why does this function return true?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, lambda, functional-programming

```
const res = (n => {
  const even = x => {
    if (x === 0)
      return true
    else {
      const odd = y => !even(y)
      return odd(x - 1)
    }
  }
  return even(n)
})(42)

console.log(res) //=> true
```

since 42 was used in the paramtersbut it says to return true only if x is 0 with strictly equaling its type and value, I'm not sure why true is returned. I thought any value but 0 should return false. Can someone please explain this to me, I am very new to javascript and programming.

Comment: The function is looping through subtracting 1 until it reaches 0 then returns true. Here you can see it at work: https://repl.it/KRZa

Comment: @Baruch what happens with `43` ? https://repl.it/KRZa

Comment: It should be noted that this is an absurdly impractical and inefficient way to check if a number is even. Never write this code if you plan to actually *use* it.

Answer (score 6):

If you strip all unnecessary parts with local functions and IIFE, then you get just a test for zero, then it's an even value or a recursive call of not even with a reduced value by one.

```js
const even = x => x === 0 || !even(x - 1);

console.log(even(42)) // true
console.log(even(43)) // false
```

> Whats happens is a recursive call of `even`
>
> ```
>  n  result of calling  simplified
> --  -----------------  ----------
>  8  !even(7)           !even(7)
>  7  !!even(6)          even(6)
>  6  !!!even(5)         !even(5)
>  5  !!!!even(4)        even(4)
>  4  !!!!!even(3)       !even(3)
>  3  !!!!!!even(2)      even(2)
>  2  !!!!!!!even(1)     !even(1)
>  1  !!!!!!!!even(0)    even(0)
>  0  !!!!!!!!true       true
> ```

Comment: or `even = (num) => !(num % 2);`

Comment: @keja, right, but the original function is to count down the parameter until zero and then stop the iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Lets simplify.

Step 1

```
const f = n => {
    const even = x => {
        if (x == 0)
            return true
        else {
            const odd = y => !even(y)
            return odd(x - 1)
        }
    }

    return even(n)
}
```

Step 2

```
const f = n => {
    const even = x => {
        if (x == 0) return true
        return !even(x - 1)
    }

    return even(n)
}
```

Step 3

```
const f = n => {
    let modificator = true

    while (true) {
      if (n == 0) return modificator
      modificator = !modificator
      n = n - 1
    }
}
```

Step 4

```
const f = n => !(n % 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works by doing negations even/odd times using recursion. Even times negating `true` gives `true`. Odd times negating `true` gives `false`. Forget `42` check `1` and `2`.

If you open up console, you can see stack trace as well.

```
return even(2) =>
even(2) => odd(2 - 1)
odd(1) => return !even(1)
!even(1) => ! (odd(1-1))
! (odd(0)) => ! ( !(even(0))) => even(0)
even(0) => true
```

---

```
return even(1) =>
even(1) => odd(1 - 1)
odd(0) => !even(0)
!even(0) => !(true) => false
```

> x is 0 with strictly equaling its type and value, I'm not sure why
>   true is returned

This happens at the tail of recursion, this `true` is switched back and forth between `true` and `false` as each recursive call completes using the negation at `!even(y)`

```js
const res = ((n) => {
    const even = (x) => {
        if (x === 0) {
            console.log(x);
            console.trace();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            const odd = (y) => !even(y);
            console.log(x);
            console.trace();
            return odd(x - 1);
        }
    }
    return even(n)
})(2) //=> true

console.log(res);
```